# C# copy a table from a word document and add it to another word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk, clonenode, openxml-table

I want to get a table from a MS Word document and add that table to another document with all it's formatting. I am using OOXML to do this. To identify a specific table I have assigned "Alt Text -> Title" and I am able to get table and it's content from source document. I have added a table to destination document with specific "Alt Text -> Title and able to get it also.

I have used below code to add table to destination document. However when I open destination document it is displaying MS Word error message.

MS Word Error -> "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened."

When I click Ok for this error it is displaying message "Word found unreadable content in .docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes." when I click Yes.

It displays the destination document with the table and all it's formatting.

How can I remove this error/warning message? What I am doing wrong with code which is causing this error?

**NOTE:** The table I am trying copy having some text with **Hyperlink** and that is causing issue. If I remove hyperlink it works fine.

```
TableProperties tableProperty = sourceDocument.Document.Body.Descendants<TableProperties>().Where(tp => tp.TableCaption != null && tp.TableCaption.Val.InnerText.Contains("sourceTable")).FirstOrDefault();

TableProperties destTableProperty = destinationDocument.Document.Body.Descendants<TableProperties>().Where(tp => tp.TableCaption != null && tp.TableCaption.Val.InnerText.Contains("destinationTable")).FirstOrDefault();

sourceTable = (Table)tableProperty.Parent;
destinationTable = (Table)destTableProperty.Parent;
destinationTable.InsertBeforeSelf<Table>((Table)sourceTable.CloneNode(true));
destinationTable.Remove();
```

Comment: A good way to track this kind of thing down is to save the repaired document to a different file name. Try to open the original document in the Open XML SDK tool and use the "Compare" functionality to open the repaired document. That will show you the differences in the Word Open XML **and** the code necessary to create the second document from the first. If the tool cannot open the first document, open the repaired one and compare the code the tools generates to create the table with the code you're using.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The Open XML SDK tool helps to validate and compare document. However the Open XML SDK tool displays validation errors for a fresh new document as well. So bit confuse how it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question was able how to copy a table from one Word document to another and the aforementioned code works fine to achieve the same.

The cause of warning/error message about document getting corrupt was due to a hyperlink within text of table. If I remove hyperlink it works fine.

For hyperlink issue I will post separate question and closing this one.